# Unable to unload a module in linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I just tried to register a net device in linux so i wrote a small program to register a net device. The c program contain code to just register the net device . 
After doing

```
# insmod net_device.ko
```

i am able to see `net_device` in /proc/modules file.

when i do

```
# rmmod net_device
```

**output:**

```
Device busy or Resource busy
```

Then i tried

```
# rmmod -f net_device
```

**output:**

```
Device busy or Resource busy
```

when i do

```
# modprobe -rf net_device 
net_device  module not found
```

I have enabled **CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=Y** in the **kernel 2.6.34.13** .

when i see `/proc/modules` is

```
net_device 12383 1 Loading 0xf423 (p+)
```

what is the meaning of **p+**

Is there any other way to kill the module?

Thank you

Comment: Did you use `lsof` or `netstat` to understand which process is using that network interface???

Comment: `lsof` or `netstat` won't show that, `lsmod` will.

Comment: `lsmod` is not able to show the processes using that network driver.

Comment: yes i agree with Basile. check the process that is using the network interface, kill it if possible and then try unloading the module